# MEAN web app database connection on Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, mean-stack

I am working on a new project of MEAN STACK web app. My application is working well in local server but facing a problem in database connection with application on Azure. I am using mongojs for database connection in my code.

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var cors = require('cors')
// database connectivity code
var mongojs = require('mongojs')
var db = mongojs("localhost:27017/shopkeeper", ["users"])
```

Comment: Your connection string is pointing to `localhost` - are you changing that connection string when pushing your app to Azure? If not, I'm guessing that's your issue.

Comment: Should it be like this??                                                                                            // database connectivity code
 var mongojs = require('mongojs')
// var db = mongojs("localhost:27017/shopkeeper", ["users"])

var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://onlineshopkeeperdb:connectionstring", function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});

Comment: I have tried but still getting same problem, so please be more specific.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by being more specific: Your code points to a database that's running locally. If you push your to Azure, and you don't change your connection string, then your local database is no longer available (unless you're pushing to a VM and running MongoDB in your VM). Also: Always *edit* your question to include more details, especially code. Please don't post code snippets as comments; very difficult to read without proper formatting. Plus I can't tell what you're asking, about that code snippet.